# Elasticsearch query to count number of hits for each API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have to get the counts of different Https responses for each API/url and display the top 5 most hit API as an Kibana Alert.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "from": "now-15m",
                        "to": "now",
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1
    }
},
"aggregations": {
    "Status": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "data.response.status",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
                {
                    "_count": "desc"
                },
                {
                    "_key": "asc"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

From this query I am able to fetch the counts of http statuses for the last 15 mins.

```
    "aggregations": {
    "Status": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 47,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "doc_count": 252095,
                "key": 200
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 3845,
                "key": 400
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 1102,
                "key": 404
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 853,
                "key": 401
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 694,
                "key": 206
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 305,
                "key": 500
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 166,
                "key": 204
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 61,
                "key": 429
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 56,
                "key": 403
            },
            {
                "doc_count": 40,
                "key": 422
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Since I am new to elasticsearch I am unable to write multiple aggregation with "data.url" field to fetch the count of http status for each API/url.

I am expecting something like this

```
API               
/search/results  200 : 30 201: 10 500:1
/eligibility     200 : 20 500 : 3
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great start, you're almost there!

You just need to add another `terms` aggregation on top of the status one, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "from": "now-15m",
              "to": "now",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "Url": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "url_field_name",                      <----- add this 
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "data.response.status",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_key": "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am able to get top API with counts of each statuses. But is it possible to get the percentage as well for each status. I saw few blogs and posts saying percentage is not possible in elasticsearch and also in few places I could see percentage is  possible with bucket_script. Any idea on this if percentage can be calculated?

Comment: @augustinevijay I suggest you create a new thread (maybe referencing this one) for this new need

Comment: Created a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68736366/elasticsearch-query-to-calculate-percentage-of-http-statuses-of-api . Help me out in this.