# Elasticsearch query to calculate percentage of http statuses of API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to calculate the percentage of each status of an API.

Reference thread : [Elasticsearch query to count number of hits for each API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714153/elasticsearch-query-to-count-number-of-hits-for-each-api)

With the help from above thread I was able to get the counts of statuses of Top 5 APIs. Along with that I want to calculate the percentage as well.

Currently I have my query like this

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "from": "now-15m",
                        "to": "now",
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1
    }
},
"aggregations": {
    "Url": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "data.url.keyword",
            "size": 5,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
                {
                    "_count": "desc"
                },
                {
                    "_key": "asc"
                }
            ]
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "Status": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "data.response.status",
                    "size": 5,
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                    "order": [
                        {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        },
                        {
                            "_key": "asc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I get the output as below

```
"aggregations": {
    "Url": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 940,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 52374,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "Status": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "doc_count": 3261,
                            "key": 200
                        },
                        {
                            "doc_count": 254,
                            "key": 400
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "doc_count": 3515,
                "key": "/account/me"
            },
            {
                "Status": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "doc_count": 3376,
                            "key": 200
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "doc_count": 3385,
                "key": "/PlanDetails"
            },
            {
                "Status": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "doc_count": 3282,
                            "key": 200
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "doc_count": 3282,
                "key": "/evaluation"
            },
            {
                "Status": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "doc_count": 3205,
                            "key": 200
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "doc_count": 3205,
                "key": "/user/me"
            },
            {
                "Status": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "doc_count": 3055,
                            "key": 200
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "doc_count": 3055,
                "key": "/user"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

So I could get my top 5 hit APIs along with their statuses and counts. But I would also like to get percentage of statuses of each API

Something like this

```
API               
/search/results  200 : 30(89%) 201: 10(10%) 500:1(1%)
/eligibility     200 : 20(90%) 500 : 3(10%)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should post the full question here

Comment: @tomr Apologies if my question is vague. I have posted my full question. Any idea regarding this would be a big help.

Comment: Great. Can you also post the full output, not just the `aggregations` bit?

Comment: I'll post as an answer once I have a full example to draw on, but the TL;DR version is this: do that calculation client-side. So it could be helpful to have more information about how you are connecting to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of calculation should be done the client.

For example, in the following snippet from the response:

```
            {
                "Status": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "doc_count": 3261, <--- divide this
                            "key": 200
                        },
                        {
                            "doc_count": 254, <---- or this 
                            "key": 400
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "doc_count": 3515, <--- by this
                "key": "/account/me"
            },
```

Using the per-URL `doc_count` you can calculate numbers like:

```
API               
/account/me  200 : 3261(93%) 400: 254(7%)
```